# Temporarily disable Vim keybindings in Spacemacs

Tags: emacs, evil-mode, spacemacs

I have Spacemacs installed with Evil-mode enabled. Sometimes when someone who is used to Emacs is using my Spacemacs I want to disable the Vim keybindings and have regular Emacs bindings.

Is it possible to toggle (enable or disable) the Vim keybindings in Spacemacs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `dotspacemacs-editing-style` variable in the dotfile to `'emacs` and reload the dotfile, I think its `SPC f e R` by default. When you want your Vim keybindings back, change the variable to `'vim` and reload it again.

Comment: Thanks. I think CTRL-Z it changing the editing style as well. `SPC f e R` is bound to `sync-configuration-layers`.

Comment: Yes, CTRL-Z does it for the buffer you are in. If that's what you need - to give another person the ability to edit the current buffer without switching buffers, using dired etc. - then CTRL-Z is exactly what you need. If on the other hand you want to temporarily switch off Vim keybindings for the entire emacs session, then consider my suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

You can toggle Evil-mode with CTRL-Z which is bound to `evil-emacs-state`.